# I need help identifying this bonsai tree

Tags: identification, bonsai

i bought this bonsai tree in a local gardening store.
I forgot to ask what species it was.
I can't find any useful information on the website of the importer and i was unable to identify it by means of an online guide.
Kind of dumb to assume the species wouldn't matter, but i hope one of you can help me out.

Thanks in advance :)[image: unidentified bonsai tree][image: slight zig-zag shape]

Comment: A closeup of a few leaves taken from above might be informative.

Comment: I figured someone might say that. I upload one asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Ilex crenata, a type of holly now often used as a substitute for Boxwood topiary in milder areas since Box developed a big problem with Blight.

It is an outdoor plant, but won't cope with temperatures below 5 deg C, particularly as a bonsai. It will benefit from being stood outdoors during the summer months in a shady or dappled shade spot (but depends what part of the world you're in, it won't like very high temperatures). Care instructions in the link below

http://www.bonsaidojo.net/ilex-crenata-bonsai/

Comment: I live in southern germany and have a south facing window and a balcony with spots in the shade. As long as the sun is out the tree will get sunlight. The weather is pretty stable these days. We barely get below 10°C at night. I will place it outside during the day and take it inside when the sun set so it doesn't get damaged if there is a sudden temperature drop. Thank you

Comment: Make SURE you don't forget to bring it in at night!  Are you saying this bonzai is in direct sunlight?  All summer?  You might have to acclimate it back into your home for winter...you are already doing this by bringing it in at night but try getting it out of the direct sunlight for a few weeks before bringing it inside for the winter.  10 degrees C is equal to 40ish?  Getting too cold for this bonzai...roots are the most vulnerable part of a plant.  In a pot horribly vulnerable...in a tiny pot with compromised roots (normal for bonzai) absolutely vulnerable to cold.  Don't take chances...